# Contour plot in matlab - takes forever

Tags: matlab, vectorization, contour

I am trying do a contour plot in matlab. However, the syntax seems to be correct but the matlab is taking forever to plot this as the matrix could be really large.

Please suggest what can I do about this.

Below is my code:

```
s = 10000000;
eta_gamma = zeros(s/10000);

for g1= 1:10000:s
for g2 = 1:10000:s
    eta_gamma(g1,g2) = floor((1000000000 - g1 - g2)/ (200000*(1 + floor(-0.001 + 20000*(0.001 + (0.1 + 0.9/ (1 + (-1000000 + 5000000* lambertw(power(exp(1), 0.2 + g1/5.E6)/5.))/1.E6))/ 100.))) + 75000*(1 + floor(-0.001 + 20000*(0.002 + (0.2 + 0.8/ (1 + (-8000000 + 4000000* lambertw(2* power(exp(1),2 + g2/4.E6)))/8.E6)) /200.)))));
end
end

figure
contour(eta_gamma)
```

Comment: Are you sure the bottleneck is the plotting? Having you run through profiler?

Comment: Is it the `contour` command that is taking a long time? Or your nested for loops?

Comment: It would be enough to print something before the plotting command and after, to see that the plotting takes no time..

Comment: It's totally your loops.  Look how large `s` is and look how large your step size is.  There are thousands of values you're iterating over in your nested `for` loops.  The culprit is most definitely your loops, not the plotting.  This is compounded with the fact that you are calling `lambertw` at each iteration.  Add the fact that you are experiencing function overhead to your slow execution time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the bottleneck is because of the *two heavy nested loops* there. The solution is of course [`vectorization`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) with the intention to remove those two loops. One of the best tools for `vectorization`, [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) could be used here. The final vectorized implementation listed next ran in **`1.323403 seconds`** at my end, whereas the original nested loopy version was taking forever and using up a lot of memory. Here's the code -

```
%// Input parameter
s = 10000000;

%// Define 1D arrays corresponding to each nested loop
G1 = 1:10000:s;
G2 = 1:10000:s;

%// Perform the calculations in a vectorized manner in three parts:

%// Part1: Do vectorized "1000000000 - g1 - g2"
p1 = 1000000000 - bsxfun(@plus,G1,G2.'); %//'

%// Part2: Do vectorized operations for everything involving G1 (nested loop-I)
p2 = 200000*(1 + floor(-0.001 + 20000*(0.001 + (0.1 + 0.9./ (1 + (-1000000 + ...
    5000000* lambertw(power(exp(1), 0.2 + G1/5.E6)/5.))./1.E6))/ 100.)));

%// Part3: Do vectorized operations for everything involving G2 (nested loop-II)
p3 = 75000*(1 + floor(-0.001 + 20000*(0.002 + (0.2 + 0.8./(1 + (-8000000 + ...
    4000000* lambertw(2* power(exp(1),2 + G2/4.E6)))/8.E6)) /200.)));

%// Finally combine all parts into a 2D array output, which would be eta_gamma
eta_gamma_vectorized = floor(p1./bsxfun(@plus,p2,p3.')); %//'

%// Plot results
figure, contour(eta_gamma_vectorized)
```

Here's the plot result -

[image]

Comment: Nice analysis my friend. +1.